# dealing with GridView and Custom Validation, both client and serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview, customvalidator

I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem.

What I'm trying to do:
Go through a gridview with multiple rows, and force the user to enter in specific values if certain textboxes or drop down lists are left on the default value.

What I tried:

1. Tried client side requirements, by use of the focusout event in javascript. Focus goes onto these fields depending on the previous selections users make, that part works. My code:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var text = $(row).find("input[name*='txtCurriculum']").val('enter lesson/unit name here'); 
var ddl = $(row).find("select[name*='ddlCurrAdditions']");
$(ddl).focusout(function () {
    if (ddl.val == "-select curriculum name-") {
        $(ddl).focus();
        alert("select a curriculum name before moving on");
    }
});

$(text).focusout(function () {
    if (text.val == 'enter lesson/unit name here') {
        $(text).focus();
        alert('enter in a lesson or unit name before moving on');
    }
});
```

It never fired properly. the ddl focusout would fire, but wouldn't stop firing until I exited and went back to the page. the text focusout would never fire.

2. Tried server side validation, with the custom validation feature.

```
protected void cv1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    CustomValidator cv = ((CustomValidator)(source));
    GridViewRow gvr;

    //if (FormCGrid.Rows)
    foreach (GridViewRow row in FormCGrid.Rows)
    {
        //string ddl = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlCurrAdditions")).SelectedItem.Text;

        string txtC = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtCurriculum")).Text;
        bool ddl = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlCurrAdditions")).Visible;

        if (txtC == "enter lesson/unit name here")
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
            cv.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Please enter the Additional program name on row {0}", row.RowIndex);      
        }
        else if (ddl == true)
        {
            cv.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Enter your lesson or unit for the curriculum selected on row  {0}", row.RowIndex);
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to loop through the rows of the gridview here, checking the named dropdown for visibility (hidden until another dropdownlist reveals it, dependent on the value chosen there) and the textbox for the default value, yet this did not work either. It never fired at all. Any suggestions welcome.

I am generally ok with most programming/coding issues, but I find that working with the asp.net gridview, all of my techniques get thrown out the window.

Comment: When should this validations occur? If on a button click then on the 1st method you should override the click method. On the second method you did not specified what problem you got.

Comment: Validation should occur when the user clicks to save. Made the edit to inform what happened on method 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are two ways to do this, and you can use js quite easy here. However, lets go with a 100% server side code. I think sticking to server side code is easier.

Next up? I actually STONG suggest to use a listview in place of a gridview WHEN you plan to edit data. The reason is simple - the ListView does not require those "irratating" "item template" over and over for each asp.net control you want to drop/have in that grid display. Now to be fair, say 2-3 controls - then grid view is ok, but for more, then I really find that the listview starts to win here big time (no need for the item template).
The "trick" with listview is of course to setup a datasoruce on the web page, let it generate the markup, and then blow out (delete) all templates except for the item template. And then delete the datasourc1 item on the page, and remove the datasource1 setting from the list view.

However, lets go with the grid view - this will thus be some what "more messy"

So, we going to fill out the grid - and say we want a city combo box - MUST be selected. And lets toss in a basic check for say LastName also must be entered.

So, we have a city combo box (database driven). And say lets toss in a drop down for a hotel rating (1-5) - but that's only 5 choices - so we have that dropdown with the list in mark-up. (so two combo examples to show how this works).

So, say we have a grid like this, and we hit save, we get this result:

[image]

Now, of course we would fancy up that message box area. And in fact, we could VERY easy drop in jQuery.UI and make that cute div on the right appear in a dialog box (and we can trigger that box + jQuery.UI dialog display even from our server side code behind - but lets try and keep this short - but I would fancy up that error message area).

Ok, first the markup:

Just a simple grid, but "a bit messy" due to those "item Templates - (if you not figured this out, I really dislike those template things!!! - and with listview you don't need them!! - just drop in pure clean asp.net controls for the grid). Anyway:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                
        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="HotelName" >
            <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="HotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="FirstName" >
            <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="LastName" >
            <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" DataTextField="City" 
                    DataValueField = "City" Width="110px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
            <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox id="Active" runat="server"  Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'  /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRating" runat="server" SelectedValue = '<%# Eval("Rating") %>' >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Poor</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Just Ok</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Ok</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Good</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Excellent</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
</div>

    <div id="ErrorDialog" style="display:normal;float:left;padding-left:30px;width:20%" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtErrors" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="width:100%" Rows="20"   ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

<div style="clear:both;padding-top:20px">
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdUnDo" runat="server" Text="UnDo" Style="margin-left:20px"/>
</div>
```

Ok, now on SO? Gee, that is about the total max markup I would post in one shot - beyond above, we approach the "not very nice" post territory.

Ok, so lets look at the code to load up this grid. We have this code:

```
public class EditHotelsG : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private DataTable rstTable = new DataTable();
private DataTable rstCity = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Web.UI.Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        ErrorDialog.Visible = false;

        LoadGrid();
        ViewState["rstTable"] = rstTable;
        ViewState["rstCity"] = rstCity;
    }
    else
    {
        rstTable = ViewState["rstTable"];
        rstCity = ViewState["rstCity"];
    }
}


public void LoadGrid()
{

    // load up our drop down list from database (city)
    string strSQL;

    strSQL = "SELECT City from tblCity Order by City";

    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

        rstCity.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

        // now load up main grid view

        strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Active, Rating from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";

        cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL;

        rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);
        GridView1.DataSource = rstTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    // set combo box data source
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        // setup city drop down list

        DropDownList cboDrop = e.Row.FindControl("cboCity");
        cboDrop.DataSource = rstCity;
        cboDrop.DataBind();
        cboDrop.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty));     // add blank row

        cboDrop.Text = rstTable.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex).Item("City").ToString;
    }
}
}
```

Ok, now that is not all that much code. And a good part was setting up that combo box. Since the cbo box (dropdown list) was database driven, then we have to bind + setup for each row.  So, that cost us a good chunk of our coding time.

Note however how we persist the database soruce (table). We do that, since we want to with A LOT LESS code, update the whole database behind in ONE shot. By peristing that table, then we

```
Transfer data from Grid to table
Save the table to database in one shot
```

So, this reduces our coding efforts by a truckload.

The code to save our data, thus becomes this gem:
(and note how we ALSO put in our validation code).

```
protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

// pull gride rows back to table.
bool bolDataOk = true;
txtErrors.Text = "";

foreach (GridViewRow rRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    int RecordPtr = rRow.RowIndex;

    DataRow OneDataRow;
    OneDataRow = rstTable.Rows(RecordPtr);

    OneDataRow.Item("HotelName") = rRow.FindControl("HotelName") as TextBox.Text;
    OneDataRow.Item("FirstName") = rRow.FindControl("FirstName") as TextBox.Text;
    OneDataRow.Item("LastName") = rRow.FindControl("LastName") as TextBox.Text;
    OneDataRow.Item("City") = rRow.FindControl("cboCity") as DropDownList.Text;
    OneDataRow.Item("Active") = rRow.FindControl("Active") as CheckBox.Checked;
    OneDataRow.Item("Rating") = rRow.FindControl("cboRating") as DropDownList.SelectedValue;

    // check for missing City, or LastName
    if (IsDBNull(OneDataRow("City")) | OneDataRow("City") == "")
    {
        bolDataOk = false;
        if (txtErrors.Text != "")
            txtErrors.Text += Constants.vbCrLf;
        txtErrors.Text += "Missing City on row = " + (rRow.RowIndex + 1).ToString;
    }

    if (IsDBNull(OneDataRow("LastName")) | OneDataRow("LastName") == "")
    {
        bolDataOk = false;
        if (txtErrors.Text != "")
            txtErrors.Text += Constants.vbCrLf;
        txtErrors.Text += "Missing lastName on row = " + (rRow.RowIndex + 1).ToString;
    }
}

ErrorDialog.Visible = !(bolDataOk);

// now send table back to database with updates

if (bolDataOk)
{
    string strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Active, Rating from tblHotels WHERE ID = 0";
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter daupdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(daupdate);

        daupdate.Update(rstTable);
    }
}
}
```

Now, once again, that above code snip is a wee bit long - and is aobut the max size of a code snip for SO. I would perhaps consider breaking out that above last code into 2 or even 3 routines.

but, all in all, the above shows quite a few tricks, and approaches here.

As noted, I was going to post how you can/could verify using client side code, ,but the OVER ALL idea of saving back the whole grid with one database update? Well, I would use that trick with a listview, gridview, and even if I was doing client side js verification? I will still use the bulk of the above design pattern.

And the un-do button? Well, I never finished that part - but it would just call the same code as the first page load (postback - false, and you would simply re-bind the grid from the database source for the un-do button.